# How to start with nothing on texture, then paint texture on?

Tags: texturing

On my texture painting mode, when I assign the texture to paint, it just fills the object with the texture. How can I start with blank and paint the texture on?

Comment: Try to use eraze alpha blending and set the strength to 1 to clear the texture with the brush.

Comment: Can you check out my other recent question?

Answer (score 5):

To clear the texture open UV/Image editor, set **Blend Type** to **Erase Alpha** and **Strength** to 1 and clear the image with the brush. Same can be done in 3D view paint mode.

[image]

Comment: Is there no easy way to just clear the whole canvas? Seems crazy to have to paint the whole thing.