# Saving images with transparent spacing between islands

Tags: uv, image, transparency

I am trying to save images from Blenders uv editor with transparent background but opacity on the painted parts. How can I achieve this? The reason I want to do this is because I use a filter inside my painting app that blends all the colors of the edges on each shell to prevent bleeding. This is a huge time saver. See attached pictures.

[image]

Comment: I wish to be wrong, but I think there is no way to automatically clean pixels outside the islands once it is filled. 
When you create a new image, you need to activate "Alpha" option so you start with a clean background that will allow you to save the image like you want.

Comment: Also, remember there is a Bleeding option in Texpaint > Options > Project Paint

Comment: To save images with transparency, your image should have alpha info stored into. Has it? Can you provide an example of what you are trying to save?

Comment: I always paint textures in .png. But in Photoshop i generally just have a color filled background when i paint because it's more easy visual wise. >Carlo have you looked at the picture attached?

Comment: Before you start to paint use this method in this answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28863/how-to-start-with-nothing-on-texture-then-paint-texture-on/